# How to minimize services in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I am using ubuntu from last 6-7 months. I am having 512mb ram and a p4 processor with 1.73 Ghz processing speed. And being a programmer i have to work with eclipse and netbeans like ide's, and they sometimes hang.

So is there any option in ubuntu to stop the services running just like i do have in windows "msconfig" or mycomputer->manage, and where could i find the details about the services so that i should know what will be its effect if i stop this service.
I am using ubuntu 10.10

Thanks

Comment: You're a programmer with 512MB of RAM? For God's sake, don't waste time messing around disabling bits of the OS - go out and pick up a couple of gigs.

Comment: this may be more appropriate for http://superuser.com/

Comment: @Rob If this is for work he may not be able to do that. When I was working at a place they didn't have much money and we got boxes with a P4 and 512MBs of RAM. And those were hand-me-downs from other people on site when they upgraded.

Comment: @Nathan Adams ya same here. but anyone would give answer to the question please

Comment: Installing Xubuntu would be your best bet.

Comment: ok thanks nathan. i would try it

Comment: @codeomnitrix, the correct place for you to ask this question is askubuntu.com. It is also one of the sites of stackoverflow.com, but for Ubuntu questions. Try it, I am sure they will help you! But before that, you should also try to search askubuntu.com with Google, I am sure some people have asked similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a bit of background knowledge of which are vital services which ones are not, but you can e.g. you can check System -> Prefererences -> Startup Applications or for something more radical, install a tool like sysv-rc-conf which will allow you to select what services to start at boot time (it manages the /etc/rcN.d scripts)